# Best pattern to control the return of a method

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Is there a pattern or a best option to improve this method and reduce duplicate ifs?

I've already use the Adapter pattern to transform an interface to another.

```
public string GetInvoice(int id)
{
    // Search in Mongodb and get the object
    var invoice = MongoRepository.Get<IInvoiceEntity>(x => x.Invoice.Id == id)
        .First();

    if (invoice == null) 
    {
        // Search in SQL
        invoice = EFRepository.Get<IInvoiceEntity>(x => x.Invoice.Id == id)
            .First();
    }

    if (invoice == null)
    {
        // This invoice is an old system item
        var oldInvoice = WCFClient.InvoiceService.Get(id);

        var adapter = new OldInvoiceAdapter(oldInvoice);
        invoice = adapter.AdaptEntity();
    }

    return invoce.ToJson();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would not label these as `duplicate ifs` since clearly the state that is being checked is different. Really the code looks ok to me. The only change you could do would be doing the opposite check and returning earlly `invoice` if it is not `null`, but that would be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd extract out the various strategies for getting the invoice into methods (which obviates the need for much of your commenting) and then simplify this method, like so:

```
var invoice = GetInvoiceFromMongoDb(id) 
       ?? GetInvoiceFromSql(id)
       ?? GetOldSystemInvoice(id);

return invoce.ToJson();
```

This makes your method really easy to understand, and breaks your code into modules, which will probably help you follow the Single-Responsibility Principle better.

Comment: adding my +1 here since he was 20 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 4):

The pattern of returning a given value if it's not null and using a different value if it is null is exactly what the null convalescing operator (`??`) does. This can help you write:

```
var invoice = GetFromMongo(id) ?? GetFromSQL(id) ?? GetFromOldArchive(id);
return invoice.ToJson();
```

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Indeed.

Comment: Cool! I had not thought of that. Thanks!